# Flask: How to access current user when creating forms?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-security

I have found this question asked in various ways slightly different but the answers seemed old or not quite what I was looking for.
I have a functioning Flask application with Flask-Security and some WTF Forms. Users can login, fill up forms and all, everything is fine.

Now, I have the need to access a user setting (shirt size) while creating a form so it is displayed to the user as they fill the form (so this is not a validation problem).
I added to the form file:
`from flask_security import current_user`
to access the setting `current_user.ts_size` but I am faced with the  `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ts_size'`

I understand that this means that current_user is of NoneType, the question is why? I am using the same import line in the file that defines the views without any problem. The views are decorated with `auth_required` so by the time a form needs to be created and displayed to the user, it is already check that the user is authenticated.
What am I missing?

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from flask_security import current_user

class JacketForm(FlaskForm):
  material = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()],)
  size = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()], description=current_user.ts_size)
```

Comment: Have you read this one https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#alternative-tokens ?

Comment: Thanks. After going through it, I am not sure it answers my question. It seems to me like it is addressing the general problem of having a custom current_user maintained. The current_user works in my application without any issue. I might be wrong, but the problem for me could be accessing the app instance of current_user at the time the form object is created. I suppose the form "factory" is generated out of session so user is None and so when called in a session, it still is None.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on on your code. First - remember that the field definitions are class variables - so those don't change when a form is instantiated. Second - StringField doesn't have a keyword argument 'cur_size' - it does have a keyword argument 'default' - which can be a callable!

So try something like:

```
size = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()], default=lambda: current_user.ts_size)
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, this is a bad simplification. However it does not solve my problem which is accessing the data in the first place.

Comment: Please give more information - current_user is a proxy - and is only valid during a request. Note that current_user is already injected into jinja - so you can access it easily in your form - {{ current_user.ts_size }}

Comment: Hello @jwag, thanks again for taking the time. Accessing the current_user from the jinja template is fine but requires to make specific treatment for that field. I would have liked, as much as possible to attached the extra information from the form definition so that I could still have a simple loop in the template. I could then just test for the extra data existence and display it.

Comment: You didn't mention why using 'default' with a lambda wasn't sufficient. I assume you are instantiating your form as part of a view, when the user issues a GET. You can always set a form value - form.size.data = current_user.ts_size

Answer (score 0):

The statement:

```
size = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()], description=current_user.ts_size
```

may be correct, but not appropriate.

Remember Flask handles view functions, models, templates and forms separately. Therefore, the size field should only be allowed to pick a field which is Sting type, as you have specified and perhaps validators. Not the `user` as you have specified above, if the concept of separation is to be maintained.

In the `view` function is where you now link the `size field` to the `current user`. You can do this by: While in the `view function` that calls the the `JacketForm`, call the current user id using  `current_user.get_id`. With the user's id then  use it query for the `ts_size` field, pick the string value and store it there.
You will need the import statement `from flask_login import current_user` in the view function to ensure that it is the current user, that is, the user logged in, is the one allowed to fill in the `JacketForm`.
Remember also this will happen if your model - database correctly connects the `user table` to the `jacket table` or whichever name you have given it, through correct relationship.

I have just tried to explain what I will do without writing any code, mainly because you have only provided one form. It is not clear how you have defined your view functions or tables in the database to have an overall picture. And if you are able to it, then you will be learning. The take way is that the `size` field in the `JacketForm` should never have the user specified there, only the type of field and validators. What the field finally picks is provided in the `view` function that makes use of the `JacketForm`.